# how to determine how much speed a motor will produce under load?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors

I am working on a one-wheel project, I would like to use an electric go kart motor chain driven to a 30 cm diameter wheel and get 90 kg at least 13 m/s with an acceleration of 3 m/s<sup>2</sup>, I would like to be able to climb 20% grade hills. Can someone help me calculate how much motor wattage is required so I can decide on motor and battery?

Comment: A half decent starting point is simply the energy equation...E=1/2*m * v^2....

Answer (score 0):

A cart,  once it gets to steady speed will have to fight only  tires kinetic friction which is a number in the order of 1%, mechanical friction, drag produced the air passing around it. .

All of these factors depend on your design and the efficiency of the individual components.

Typically electric carts use one kilowatt power.

Many vendors of 48 volt motors and batteries and cart assemblies have some data on the performance of their kits.